# Including repeating features into rnn input vector

Tags: rnn, lstm, data-science-model

My question is - will recurrent network such as lstm or recursive network learn anything from features that are being repeated over multiple timesteps.

So for example I have a charachter based model for text generation, and besides the actual letter I want to include the meta information about the word that this character belongs to - like part of speech role. If would to concatenate a spared vector representing this information to each letter vector of each word.

Thank you.